# What is the smallest you can make a (Oracle JVM) java heap?

Tags: java

java accepts -Xmx1k happily as an argument, but "experiments show" this is still really something like an 8MB heap.

Googling didn't turn up anything to use, so I'm wondering, what is the smallest heap size you can mandate in Java?

Thanks,
Eric

Edit:

It seems to vary a bit by platform and java version.  On my Mac, with 1.6.0_24, the smallest I can configure it without error is:

```
$ java -Xms1k -Xmx4097k -XX:NewSize=192k  -cp . Foo
5636096
```

or about 5.375M, where Foo.java is just:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    }
}
```

My environment is thus:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin turbo.local 10.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.0: Sat Jan 29 15:17:16 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.9.37~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)
```

As I mentioned in a comment below, I was setting a small heap trying to verify that an expensive algorithm really was using almost no memory, not trying to save money.

Thanks for the answers -- I was despondent at how little useful came up when I tried to google this.

Comment: I've never seen it set less than 32MB, that too back in the days. I've never tried to figure out the minimum though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are working on an extremely limited mobile device (in which case you should do your testing on that device) even 8MB isn't much

A server costs about $70/GB or about 50 cents per 8 MB.

Running with options `-mx1m -XX:NewSize=256k` The following

```
System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1024);
```

Prints

```
2304
```

which is 2.25 MB.

Don't forget, the heap is not the entire application. You have permgen and share libraries to include in the total size.

Comment: I wasn't actually worrying about money, I was just testing an algorithm that I was pretty sure was heavy on the speed side of the speed-for-space tradeoff, so I was trying to set the max heap size as low as possible to confirm it still worked.  But of course asking the JVM how much memory it has is the way to go, thanks.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: $70/GB per what?  Are you talking about the price to buy ECC ram?  Are you taking into account the energy consumption of the ram?  Is it per month?  Per year?  That is really one weird statement I think and I don't really understand how the price relates to the question asked :)  (honest comment : )

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r, You shouldn't need to worry about 8 MB of memory unless you have a very restricted system. The cost of memory is very small. Memory is reusable, but your time is not.  By "$70/GB" I meant $70 per GB.  You can buy a name vendor server with 8 GB for ~$560 and a 1 TB server for around $70K with about the same power consumption as the server you are using now.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r, I find developers often don't think of the whole problem and the impact to the business. Even businesses will happily spend thousands of dollars on staff, to avoid spending hundreds of dollars on hardware. I find this bend but normal. ;)  But this equations can get insanely unbalanced.  If you cost the your employer $100 per hour, its not worth you spending even 1 minute to save 10 MB of memory. Yet developers will happily spend many minutes or hours trying to save a few MB, a few KB or even worring about whether to use `int` or `long`.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: so you meant *"$70 per GB as a one-time acquisition cost"*.  I asked because it is so common now to rent computing power and to take into account the power bill etc.  If the OP is indeed working on server-based-not-in-the-cloud things, then not worrying about optimization may be fine.  But if he's working in the embedded/mobile/desktop world or for a company that rents CPU/ram on-demand, then optimization may still matters.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I don't disagree with you but you're in a mindset *"developers-working-on-one-server-side-application-running-on-one-machine"*.  Once a developer works on an application deployed on thousands of systems, the equation optimization/price-per-ram changes suddenly a lot.  (I've worked both on mobile and desktop apps, as well as on server-side-running-on-just-one-server stuff).

Comment: @Syntaxt3rr0r, If you are saving 1 MB on one thousand machines that is 1 GB of memory total. Save 10 MB on ten thousand machines is 100 GB in total. You only really save memory if that memory is used for something else instead.  Leaving more of a system unused saves nothing. I don't see that the equation changes at all. ;) Mobile devices tend to be a different story as you have no control over the hardware it is run on.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I can tell you don't have control over the hardware your average destkop user has nor how he's using it.  The number of times people have reported "issues" just so that we could diagnose a memory-leak in a browser opened since too long, with too many "prefetched webpages", etc.  is insane.  On **most** user desktops there's a *lot* of swapping involved when the user switches from *some-browser* to your desktop app.  10MB saved times *x thousands users* is a lot of headaches spared, to a lot of users...  I mean, there's a reason while Java still sucks for Desktop apps ;)

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r, Alot of desktops in various companies are fairly limited, This is not a technical issue, but a reality. A 16 GB desktop costs about $1000 to buy.  If you have to buy alot of these you can save money here and there but it just adds to development and support costs.  Where the right balance is depends of the team/company but the shift is towards memory being a consumable like printer paper. ;)

Answer (score 4):

From the docs at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

> *-Xmxn: This value must a multiple of 1024 greater than 2MB*

And my quick test shows that:

`java -Xmx2M HelloWorld`

works on 1.6.0_24

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't "happily" accept it.

```
broach@broach-laptop:~/NetBeansProjects$ /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java -Xmx1k
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small initial heap
```

This is Oracle JVM 1.6.0_20

My "experiment" shows that anything less than `-Xmx5M` gives you that error.

**EDIT:** I Experimented more ... `-Xmx4100k` seems to fly.

Comment: Try reducing the NewSize to 512k, ;)

Comment: $ java -Xmx1k -cp . Foo
hello, world
ebowman@turbo 09:52:28 15/04 ~/src/logic
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I was recently researching this topic of smallest heap possible for OpenJDK and I found following.

The first aspect is how small number you can actually enter as a `Xmx` parameter. That is currently limited as 2MB (JDK 21). [Xmx verification code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/5fa2bdc6c76d8f70c8d8582889e96b9c0d2b86b5/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gcArguments.cpp#L136-L138) you can see the check.

However the number you enter as `Xmx` parameter doesn't always mean you will get exactly that. There is heap alignment that will round the memory up depending on architecture where you run your Java application. [Heap alignment code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/3b1062d45df69d4cf8479c6a65602bd2453ab885/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/gcArguments.cpp#L69-L85)

The alignment is dictated by memory page size. Garbage collector (G1 in my experiments) uses Card Table to track parts of heap have objects pointing to evacuated regions that needs to be updated. This card table is a simple byte array. Each element of that array is a flag for `512` bytes of heap memory. For efficiency (my guess, happy to learn more why) it is better to have card table  at size of memory page size. That will give you the ultimate heap size. My iMac Pro has `4096` bytes page size. Each byte of that will represent `512` bytes of heap so `4096 * 512 = 2,097,152 -> 2M`.

Running:

```
java -Xmx2M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize
```

Shows:

```
size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 2097152
```

This alignment of course covers not just minimal heap sizes so for example:

```
java -Xmx3M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize
```

Rounds memory up to 4MB

```
size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4194304
```

Now another example is from my M1 Macbook. The page size is `16384`.

```
java -Xmx2M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize
```

The the smallest heap for that platform is 8MB

```
size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 8388608
```